# Mendeley for e-books

Tags: webapp-rec, trello-organization, document-management

I have been using [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) for my research paper library for some time and I absolutely love the way it takes care fo organizing my library. Is there such a Web/Desktop app to organize my ebook library. I would like to put all my PDFs (and other formats) in a giant folder and the app should take care of organizing them by author, publisher, isbn, tags etc

Comment: Why not use Mendeley for the purpose? (I have my e-books in Mendeley) The ISBN resolver isn't working but maybe in some time (see: http://feedback.mendeley.com/forums/4941-mendeley-feedback/suggestions/155482-introduce-ebook-isbn-resover?ref=title)

Comment: @Piotr thats the whole point. It is very promising but right now its just not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Although NOT a web app, I use Calibre (http://calibre-ebook.com/) for my nook. It can manage eBooks and PDF docs. Additionally, it can download and convert RSS feeds. I use it like iTunes. It's open source and there is a version that runs on Windows, Apple and Linux.

Comment: It's kind of a web app... you can run a content server from it and access it from your lan or the internet :)